# php take link by path parts array

Tags: php, arrays, laravel

Work with tree category structure with latest php and laravel

I need convert path to category from array to string  for use this in view.

Category path array contains root. But path string should not contain root part.

Please help to correct my method and make it shorter and more readable

```
public function getLinkAttribute()
{

    $path_without_root = array_filter($this->path, function ($value) {
        return $value->parent_id > 0;
    });

    $link = implode(
        array_map(function($value){
            return $value->name;
        }, $path_without_root),
        "/"
    );


    return $link;

}
```

Note: i can't use laravel collections  in this context.

Comment: what part of url segment are you trying to get ?

Comment: This better to be on [codereview](https://codereview.stackexchange.com/). There will be opiniated answer going on, furthermore _shorter_ and _readable_ is like an opposite. I'd rather put a descriptive PHP comment between them to make them as really readable.

Comment: "Please help to correct my method" What's the problem?

Comment: Yeah I don't think you'll get much shorter than this, assuming this works--there isn't enough context for me to tell if this would work or not.  But otherwise you're going to be using a lot of foreach loops, which is technically faster, but if your goal is to reduce the size of the code, then you can't get much shorter than using array_filter and array_map.

Comment: this work fine. several foreach even worse

Comment: problem make readable and short